# Is it possible to change the badge color based on badge text?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is there a way for me to change the badges color based on the text? Example: If my extension is blocking 20 things it could be yellow and if it's blocking 50 things it could be red.

Comment: Yes - you can use [browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setBadgeBackgroundColor) to set the color of your badge.

Comment: @TrentonTrama I know I can change it, but the question is: Can I change the color based on the badge text?

Comment: If you have what the badge text is, you can determine what color should used when you set the badge color.

Comment: @TrentonTrama Okay, any idea how? I don't want it a specific color for a specific number I want it a specific color for a specific range on text (e.g. 0-24 could be [255, 255, 0, 255] and 25-999 could be [217, 0, 0, 255])

Comment: Write a switch-case, it is not possible automatically..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the color of the badge based on the value in it.
Since you're setting the value of the badge, you already have the value and you can dynamically determine which color to use.

Afterwards, you can use [browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setBadgeBackgroundColor) to set the color.

```
// First, define badge colors with the minimum threshold.  
// For the sake of simplicity, keep the minimums in order.
const badge_colors = [
    {min: 0, color:  [255, 255, 0, 255] },
    {min: 11, color:  [255, 255, 0, 255] },
    {min: 200, color:  [255, 255, 0, 255] }
];

const badge_counter = 34; // This should already be avaliable, but can also be fetched using browserAction.getBadgeText()


const new_badge_color = badge_colors.reverse() // Reverse the list so the min is in descending order
                                .find(color=>color.min < badge_counter) // Find the first minimum value that is less than the badge counter.

// new_badge_color is now 
// {min: 11, color:  [255, 255, 0, 255] }
```

Once you have the new color, you can set the color using `setBadgeBackgroundColor`